# How to set height and with of child layout to fit within parent layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, geometry, android-relativelayout

I am new to android and trying to make `circular layouts` using xml as background. Now I have a parent relative layout and it has a child relative layout. The parent relative layout has a background xml with corner radius and is displayed as a circle. Now the inner relative layout/child layout must also inherit this and be a circle right?, but it doesn't! the child layout has height and width as `match_parent` & `match_parent`. So how do i make the child layout's height and width fit in the circle of the parent?

```
  <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/view10"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_width="52dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/dutycirclebackground"
                    android:layout_height="52dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the **background xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#cc5228"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

here, if i set a background color to the inner layout and check the output i get a `square layout` but the `parent is a circle`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove   android:gravity="center" in child layout

Comment: @sasikumar, removed and checked, but still a square

Comment: @Sidharth MA did u run it on a actual devise ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try to this hope this can help you..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="52dp"
android:layout_height="52dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/view10"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
android:background="@drawable/dutycirclebackground"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dutycirclebackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dileep patel, it helped me!

Comment: hey i cant do neither of them as my reputation is below 15 :)

Answer (score 0):

Do as

```
  android:radius="250dp"
```

instead all corner radius:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#cc5228"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="250dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, If your parent layout is circle it doesn't mean that, your child is also be circular.

Second, In you case your parent is also not circular it is rectangle in shape, you drawable only hides its corners and show you the other part. That is why , when you use match parent or something it will give you square not circle.

use your drawable in child not parent.

or you can use [Dileep Patel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41197182/5188159) for your purpose of square inside circle